# Can't connect to remote desktop on azure virtual machine

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

I uploaded a hyper-v VHD file to storage.  I then created a Windows VM from disk and specified that it contains the operating system.   Azure says the machine is running and the remote desktop and powershell endpoints are configured.    However, When I click connect I get the standard rdp error.

I have resized the VM and restarted the VM a few times to no avail.

Clicking Reset Remote Connection has failed in the Azure Preview Portal.   This button is now disabled.

When I run (Get-AzureVM -ServiceName XXXXXX -Name XXXXXX).GuestAgentStatus  it returns:

```
ProtocolVersion   : 1.0
TimestampUtc      : 10/13/2015 2:02:29 PM
GuestAgentVersion : Unknown
Status            : NotReady
Code              :
Message           :
FormattedMessage  : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.Model.GuestAgentFormattedMessage
ExtensionData     :
```

Comment: this question is not about programming, try on superuser

Answer (score 0):

I worked with Microsoft Support in resolving this issue.  For those who have posted similar unanswered questions you need to edit the registry of the VM to disable the firewall and change the RDP security settings of the VM.

1. Delete your VM but keeping the attached disks.
2. Create a temporary VM from the gallery
3. Attach the original vhd as a disk to the temporary VM.
4. Bring the disk online, if it is not already.
5. Use Regedit to load the System hive from the attached disk under the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE key.
6. Turn off the firewall:  Check your OS Registry keys.  For a windows 7 machine: Open the following key for each of the ControlSetsXXX
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\YOURLOADEDHIVENAME\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy

Set EnableFirewall = 0 in the DomainProfile, PublicProfile and StandardProfile subkeys

7. Modify the RDP security settings: Open the following key for each of the ControlSetsXXX
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\YOURLOADEDHIVENAME\ControlSet001\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp

Set the values: fAllowSecProtocolNegotiation, SecurityLayer and UserAuthentication to 0

7. Unload the Hive
8. Take the disk offline
9. Detach the disk from the temporary VM
10. Shutdown the temporary VM and delete it
11. Create your VM as your did previously
12. Connect to your VM and rdp into it. Set the appropriate Firewall rules for RDP and turn the firewall back on.

Original information taken from:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18710.troubleshoot-azure-vm-by-attaching-os-disk-to-another-azure-vm.aspx

and

http://www.technlg.net/windows/disable-enable-firewall-registry-key/